# Error handling for missing values in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, error-handling

I would like to incorporate some error handling in the below code when the population file is missing population data for a city but I get this message.

**TypeError: descriptor 'get' requires a 'dict' object but received a 'str'**

```
import csv
import sys
import time


input_file = ('\myInput_file.csv')
output_file = ('\myOutput_file.csv')
population_file = ('\myPopulation_file.csv')

populations = {}

with open(population_file, 'r') as popfile:
    for line in csv.reader(popfile):
        populations[line[2]] = line[3]


with open(input_file, 'r') as infile, open(output_file, 'w', newline='') as outfile:
reader = csv.reader(infile)
writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter = ',')

for row in reader:

    population = dict.get(populations[row[0] + row[1]], None)
    new_line = [row[0]+row[1], population]
    writer.writerow(new_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
population = populations.get(row[0] + row[1], None)
```

The reason for the error is that `get()` is a method descriptor of the builtin type `dict`. Similar to other methods (functions that are members of a class), they require the first argument to be the object to do the operation on. Consider the following code:

```
class Thing(object):
    def get(self, something):
        # ...
```

`get()` is a method of the class `Thing`, which requires two parameters, `something`, the thing you want to get, but also `self`, the object you want to get it from.

When you call `populations.get()` (using the dict object `populations`), the object gets passed as the first argument automatically. Such is a feature of bound methods. If you call 'dict.get()' (using the dict class `dict`), it does not know what dict object to pass as the `self` argument, and you must supply it explicitly.

Consider the following:

```
>>> Thing.get
<function Thing.get at 0x103ff6730>
>>> a = Thing()
>>> a.get
<bound method Thing.get of <__main__.Thing object at 0x104002cf8>>
>>>
```

Here's what happens when you make the same error on a non-builtin class:

```
>>> Thing.get('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'something'
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!  You just save me a lot of grief